# Run system command in php

Tags: php, linux

I want to run system command in PHP.But when I run file I am getting error.  My Command like.I want to run awk command.

Code:

```
  $awk="awk '{print $1,$NF}' stat.txt";
  $awkop=shell_exec($awk);
```

Output:

```
awk: {print $1,} 
awk: ^ syntax error awk: cmd. line:1: {print $1,} 
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: awk: {print $1,}
awk:           ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print $1,}
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: add this info in question by clicking [edit] below the qeustion. I am not php expert , just trying to get question in format where someone will be able to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making use of incorrect escape and quotes due which your shell commands are passed in incorrect way to the shell.

You must rewrite it as following:

```
$awk='awk \'{print $1,$NF}\' stat.txt';
$awkop=shell_exec($awk);
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

begining of your code, there is a ` sign, please remove it first. And also make sure, you have a stat.txt file in your file execution location and writable to execution user.

```
$awk="awk '{print $1,$NF}' stat.txt";
$awkop=shell_exec($awk);
```

I tried this, no errors. Also no any output to the file ....

Comment: It would not be good idea to use $1 in double quotes, its PHP it will replace it; will try to treat it as varliable name and create issues.

Comment: Also it is `shell_exec` for output you must `echo $awkop;`.